# Search phone authentication firebase problem

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

After pressing verify button to send me the code the application opens browser and wait sometime. Nothing happens and no SMS sent to me and this toast appears to me. before you ask i made everything before, firebase and and SHA certificate fingerprints.

```
public class PhoneSingUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    TextView SignUpTXT , VerifyingTXT , ErrorTXT ;
    GifImageView VerifySuccess ;
    Button VerifyBTN , ContinueBTN ;
    CountryCodePicker ccp;
    EditText NumberEnt;
    PinView VerifyPIN;
    String VerifyCodeBySystem , Code , CountryCodeS ,UserEnteredNumber , PhoneNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_sing_up);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        SignUpTXT = findViewById(R.id.SingUpTXT);

        ccp = (CountryCodePicker) findViewById(R.id.ccp);
        NumberEnt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_carrierNumber);

        VerifyingTXT = findViewById(R.id.verifyingTXT);
        ErrorTXT = findViewById(R.id.ErrorTXT);

        VerifyPIN = findViewById(R.id.VerificationPIN);

        VerifySuccess = findViewById(R.id.VerifySuccess);

        VerifyBTN = findViewById(R.id.VerifyBTN);
        VerifyBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CountryCodeS = ccp.getSelectedCountryCode();
                UserEnteredNumber = NumberEnt.getText().toString();
                PhoneNumber = "+" + CountryCodeS + UserEnteredNumber;
                if (PhoneNumber.length() < 13){
                    ErrorTXT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    VerifyingTXT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else {
                    if (PhoneNumber.length() == 13) {
                        ErrorTXT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        VerifyingTXT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        sendVerificationCode(PhoneNumber);
                    }
                }
            }
        });



        ContinueBTN = findViewById(R.id.ContinueBTN);
        ContinueBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(PhoneSingUp.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    private void sendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(PhoneSingUp.this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            VerifyCodeBySystem = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            Code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if (Code != null){
                VerifyPIN.setText(Code);
                VerifyCode(Code);
                VerifySuccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(PhoneSingUp.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    private void VerifyCode(String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(VerifyCodeBySystem,code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        } else {

                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check this page https://stackoverflow.com/tour. It will help you to create better, more detailed and focused questions.